# How to pass python variable values to php inside html?

Tags: php, python

I have a simple python code

```
path1 = //path1/
path2 = //path2/

write_html = """

<form name="input" action="copy_file.php" method="get">

"""
Outfile.write(write_html)
```

Now copy_file.php copies files from one folder to another. I want the python path1 and path2 variable values to be passed to php script. **How can I do that?** Also instead of calling a php script, how can I place the php code in action attribute.

Php code

```
<?php
      $file = $argv[1]
      $newfile = $argv[1]

      if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
      echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
      }
```

?>

Comment: Why are you sending a request to a PHP script? Why not copy the file with Python since you're already using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
write_html = """

<form name="input" action="copy_file.php" method="get">

<input type="hidden" name="path1" value="{0}" />
<input type="hidden" name="path2" value="{1}" />

<input type="button" name="button" value="onClick="copyfile('{0}', '{1}')"/> 

<script> function moveFile(path1, path2){ ...} </script>

""".format(path1, path2)
```

Then in `copy_file.php` add

```
$path1 = $_GET["path1"];
$path2 = $_GET["path2"];
```

Comment: Can it be arrranged like js - <input type="button" name="button" value="onClick="copyfile('%s', '%s')"/>   <script>
                    function moveFile(path1, path2){ ...} </script> in php.

Comment: Sure, you are just generating php from python.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the python path1 and path2 variable values to be passed to php script.

Doable:

```
write_html = """

<form name="input" action="copy_file.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="path1" value="%s" />
<input type="hidden" name="path2" value="%s" />

""" % (path1, path2)
```

My python is a bit rusty, but that should work.

> instead of calling a php script, how can I place the php code in action attribute.

What? No. Are you insane?

**Edit:** wait, are you just trying to make an HTTP request against a PHP script from within Python?

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments to your PHP script the way you do looks like for me to be done like:

in python file

```
path1 = '//path1/'
path2 = '//path2/'

write_html = """

<form name="input" action="copy_file.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="path1" value="%s"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="path2" value="%s"/>
</form>
""" % (path1, path2)
Outfile.write(write_html)
```

this will vrite your variables to html ( you may escape them if special chars )

and on php side :

```
if isset($_POST['path1'] && $_POST['path2']) {
    $path1 = $_POST['path1'];
    $path2 = $_POST['path2'];
}
```

Comment: how can I have this on onclick() event.

Comment: using a form is simpler in your case. as params values are written into your forms inputs, you just need to add this input to yor form to enable data post `<input type="submit" />` this will produce a clickable button that triggers the HTTP POST requests to your server target : copy_file.php